# Weight of watermelons after percentage of water is evaporated.

Tags: contest-math, percentages

> A stock of watermelons of the initial weight of $500 \space\text{kg}$
>   has been put in a store for a week.
>
> Initially the percentage of water in the watermelons makes up $99 \% $
>   of the weight,at the end of the week,due to evaporation, such
>   percentage dropped to $98 \%$.
>
> How much do the watermelons weight at the end of the week ?

$A)250 \space\text{kg}$,$B) 400 \text{kg} $,$C)480 \text{kg} $,$D)495 \text{kg}$

**My effort**

I have that  water makes up  $99 \%$ of the weight of the watermelons,so it weights $495 \space\text{kg}$ .

After the week I have that $2 \% $ of the water evaporated  so we loose $\cfrac{2}{100}\cdot 495 =9,9 \text{kg}$  so the watermelons should weight $490,1 \text{kg}$ which is none of the answers given ...

The solution is given as option $A)250  \text{kg}$ ,but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said, initially water weights $495 \text{kg}$ and dry mass weights $5\text{kg}$. After the week, dry mass weights still $5\text{kg}$ and makes up $2$% of the watermelon. Then watermelons should weight $5\cdot 50 = 250(\text{kg})$.

Comment: The neatest solution, +1

Comment: Thanks for the solution.One question: what does $98 \%$ represent ?The percentage of  the percentage of water or the percentage of weight?(percentages are so confusing...)

Comment: It means that water weights 98% of watermelon.

Comment: You could call the "remainder" what it is: "dry mass".

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the comment. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your fault is that you assumed that the percentage change in water is 1%. That is not so. Rather, try solving using simultaneous equations.

Let $x$ be the water lost and $y$ be the new mass of the watermelon.

1. $500 - x = y$

2.$\dfrac{495-x}{y}\times 100$ = $98$

Then we get the simultaneous equations:

1. $100(495 - x) = 98y$
2. $500 - x = y$

The solution of $y$ here is your answer.

Answer (score -1):

At the beginning you count with 1% equivalent to 5 kg of solid mass, this mass shouldn't change for obvious reasons (it can't evaporate), nevertheless the problem is suggesting a drop of 1%, 99% to 98%.

=> Initial equivalence:

.01 => 5 kg

From the water compound now represent 98% of the total mass, where is the other 2%? well it stills being 5 kg nevertheless now represent a 2%.
to know what is the total weight, the 100% we use the following operation.

$\frac{5 kg}{0.02} = 250$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) for mathematical equations.